# Nombre de un middleware en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Al poner el middleware en `app/kernel.php`, solo funciona si es distinto de `jwt.auth`, esto es lo que tengo.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'jwt.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Y en las rutas

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function () {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthenticatedUser');
});
```

Si en vez de poner `jwt.auth` pongo `jwt.aut` u otro nombre funciona.

**UPDATE**

Estoy utilizando [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) y por lo visto tiene su propio middleware `jwt.auth` en `Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware`, pero aun asi no entiendo porque usa ese si yo estoy poniendo la ruta del mio.

Comment: ¿Lo que deseas es usar tu propio middleware en vez del que incluye JWT Auth?

Comment: Si, pero solo funciona con otro nombre y me extraña porque no está definido en ningún lado